# BigQuery Troubleshooting - Query or Google Analytics?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to query my Google Analytics tables for the past 20 days with the experiment ID of

> `zCeqsUOZSL6ESM94wH8XfA`

The current code here, currently returns no rows:

```
SELECT
  e.experimentId,
  e.experimentVariant,
  i.index=1 AS borrower_id
FROM
  `93868086.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) as hits,
  UNNEST(hits.experiment) AS e,
  UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS i
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND e.experimentId = 'zCeqsUOZSL6ESM94wH8XfA'
```

Is my current code to generic to return any values? I have attempted to simplify the query just to see if it'll return rows that have an experiment ID populated but to no avail. I am currently trying to troubleshoot if it's my query or if the backend is having an issue tracking our A/B testing data. Any critique of my code above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiple unnests along different dimensions without using an ordinal counting seems like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would return no rows if any of the array are empty.  I am not an advocate of unnesting along three independent dimensions.  But, if you want to keep all rows, use `left join`s instead of `,`:

```
FROM `93868086.ga_sessions_*` LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(hits) hit LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(hits.experiment) e LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) i
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Could you explain to me what ordinal counting is in terms of SQL?

Comment: It is actually `with offset` in BigQuery.  See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays.